# DataFrame Plot: how to sort X axis

Tags: python, pandas

I am plotting some counts from a field of dataframe (pandas) and I found that the X axis is sorted by the counts (descending order). Instead is it possible to sort by the alphabetical order of the field?

Here is the Python code:

```
df['cartype'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar')
```

This sorts by the count but I want to sort by the cartype names. Any solution?

Comment: `df['cartype'].value_counts(sort=False).plot(kind='bar')`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One option is to use the function 'sort_index', which sorts Series by index labels, after the call to 'value_counts':

```
df['cartype'].value_counts().sort_index().plot(kind='bar')
```